# ¿Cómo ordenar de forma natural los nombres de las carpetas con el módulo natsort en Python, que obtuve con os.walk?

Tags: python-3.x, windows10

Soy nuevo en Python 3. Estoy utilizando el módulo **natsort**. El objetivo es generar una estructura en árbol, en la que se obtenga un listado similar al obtenido con el Explorador de Windows.

El código inicial es el siguiente:

```
import os
from natsort import natsorted

path="C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonOrdenar Directorios/"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    directory_level = dirpath.replace(path, "")
    directory_level = directory_level.count(os.sep)
    indent = " " * 4
    print("{}{}/".format(indent*directory_level, os.path.basename(dirpath)))    

    filenames=natsorted(filenames)
    for f in filenames:
        print("{}{}".format(indent*(directory_level+1), f))
```

Y, por ejemplo, se obtiene:

1_Ordena/

```
Python_1_Ejercicio.py
Python_2_Ejercicio.py
Python_3_Ejercicio.py
Python_4_Ejercicio.py
Python_5_Ejercicio.py
Python_6_Ejercicio.py
Python_7_Ejercicio.py
Python_8_Ejercicio.py
Python_9_Ejercicio.py
Python_10_Ejercicio.py
Python_11_Ejercicio.py
Python_12_Ejercicio.py
Python_13_Ejercicio.py
Capeta_1/
Capeta_10/
Capeta_11/
Capeta_12/
Capeta_13/
Capeta_14/
Capeta_15/
Capeta_2/
Capeta_3/
Capeta_4/
Capeta_5/
Capeta_7/
Capeta_8/
Capeta_9/
```

Pero debe obtenerse:
1_Ordena/

```
Python_1_Ejercicio.py
Python_2_Ejercicio.py
Python_3_Ejercicio.py
Python_4_Ejercicio.py
Python_5_Ejercicio.py
Python_6_Ejercicio.py
Python_7_Ejercicio.py
Python_8_Ejercicio.py
Python_9_Ejercicio.py
Python_10_Ejercicio.py
Python_11_Ejercicio.py
Python_12_Ejercicio.py
Python_13_Ejercicio.py
Capeta_1/
Capeta_2/
Capeta_3/
Capeta_4/
Capeta_5/
Capeta_6/
Capeta_7/
Capeta_8/
Capeta_9/
Capeta_10/
Capeta_11/
Capeta_12/
Capeta_13/
Capeta_14/
Capeta_15/
```

**Los ficheros se ordenan de forma natural** (resultado similar al Explorador de Windows), pero no las carpetas.

¿Hay alguna solución a este problema, en el que **NO se ordenan las carpetas** de forma natural?

Answer (score 3):

Sí, hay una forma. Aunque la explicación es un poco compleja, la solución es simplemente añadir una línea a tu código.

Se trata de, dentro del bucle que tienes, reordenar los contenidos de la lista `dirnames` que recibes. Esa lista contiene los nombres de las subcarpetas de la carpeta actual, y aunque no la usas para nada en tu código, es crucial, pues el orden en que aparezcan los elementos dentro de esa lista es el orden que usará `os.walk()` para descender por esas subcarpetas en las siguientes iteraciones.

Por tanto parece que bastaría añadir esta línea, por ejemplo como primera instrucción de tu bucle:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
   dirnames = natsorted(dirnames)
```

Por desgracia esto **no va a funcionar**, debido a que no estamos ordenando la lista que venía en `dirnames`, sino creando una nueva y cambiando el valor de la variable `dirnames` para que "apunte a la nueva". No obstante la lista que originalmente venía en `dirnames` no ha sido modificada, y por tanto, en la siguiente iteración del bucle, se usará la lista original para seguir (pues la variable `dirnames` que habíamos reasignado es eliminada y sobreescrita en la siguiente iteración).

Es decir, necesitaríamos modificar `dirnames` *en el sitio* (in-place).

Las listas python se pueden ordenar usando `sorted(lista)`, que retorna una lista nueva (equivalente a lo que hemos visto que hace `natsorted`) pero también se pueden ordenar haciendo `lista.sort()`, que cambia la propia lista y la deja reordenada. Esto es lo que se conoce como ordenar *in-place*.

He mirado la documentación de `natsort` y no he encontrado que tenga ningún método para ordenación *in-place* (lo que me extraña bastante, tal vez no he mirado bien).

En cualquier caso podemos hacer uso del siguiente (feo) truco:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
   dirnames[:] = natsorted(dirnames)
```

En este caso el valor retornado por `natsorted()` se usa para **reemplazar** lo que había en la lista original, debido al uso del slice `[:]`. En definitiva, la lista original queda también reordenada produciendo el resultado que buscabas.

Answer (score 0):

Muchísimas gracias. Prácticamente funciona perfecto.

Pero el problema es que el código final, incorporando la línea `dirnames[:] = natsorted(dirnames)`, no ordena de manera análoga al "Explorador de Windows".
Con el "Explorador de Windows", el orden que se obtiene es el siguiente:

1. Primero ordena las *carpetas*.
2. Segundo ordena los *archivos*.

Por el contrario, con el siguiente **código propuesto**:

```
import os
from natsort import natsorted

path="C:/Users/jm/Desktop/PythonOrdenar Directorios/"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    dirnames[:] = natsorted(dirnames)
    directory_level = dirpath.replace(path, "")
    directory_level = directory_level.count(os.sep)
    indent = " " * 4
    print("{}{}/".format(indent*directory_level, os.path.basename(dirpath)))    

    filenames=natsorted(filenames)
    for f in filenames:
        print("{}{}".format(indent*(directory_level+1), f))
```

El orden que se obtiene con el **código propuesto** es el siguiente:

1. Primero ordena lo *archivos*.
2. Segundo ordena las *carpetas*.

**Conclusión:**

¿Qué modificaciones se pueden incorporar al **código propuesto**, para obtener un resultado similar al que se obtiene utilizando el "**Explorador de Windows**"?

Comment: Esto es la solución a tu pregunta?

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, no es la solución a la pregunta. Faltaría modificar el "código propuesto" para que el resultado final sí ordene: 1º carpetas, 2º archivos. De forma similar al resultado que se obtiene con el Explorador de Windows.